# scala-akka:- Passing command line arguments to sbt run to locate .csv files

Tags: scala, sbt, akka-stream

I have a command line program that calculates statistics from humidity sensor data.

I also have .csv files inside `src/main/scala/data`

When i do `sbt "run data"` or `sbt "run src/main/scala/data"`

Seems like it's not able to locate .csv files and i get the result as 0.

output for `sbt "run src/main/scala/data"`

> Looking for CSV files in directory: src/main/scala/data

output for `sbt "run data"`

> Looking for CSV files in directory: data
>
> Num of processed files: 0
>
> Num of processed measurements: 0
>
> Num of failed measurements: 0
>
> Sensors with highest avg humidity:
>
> sensor-id,min,avg,max

expected output example:-

> Num of processed files: 2
>
> Num of processed measurements: 7
>
> Num of failed measurements: 2
>
> Sensors with highest avg humidity:
>
> sensor-id,min,avg,max
>
> s2,78,82,88
>
> s1,10,54,98
>
> s3,NaN,NaN,NaN

Code for reference:-

```
import java.io.File
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Framing, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object HumiditySensorStatistics {

  case class HumidityData(sum: Double, count: Int) {
    def avg: Option[Double] = if (count > 0) Some(sum / count) else None
  }

  case class SensorStats(min: Option[Double], avg: Option[Double], max: Option[Double])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val directoryPath = args(0)
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("HumiditySensorStatistics")
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val sensors = mutable.Map[String, HumidityData]()
    var failedMeasurements = 0

    println(s"Looking for CSV files in directory: $directoryPath")

    val fileSource = Source.fromIterator(() => new File(directoryPath).listFiles().iterator)
    val measurementSource = fileSource.flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(f.toPath))
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024, allowTruncation = true))
      .drop(1) // skip header line
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(line => {
        val fields = line.split(",")
        (fields(0), fields(1))
      })
    val sink = Sink.foreach[(String, String)](data => {
      val sensorId = data._1
      val humidity = data._2.toDoubleOption

      if (humidity.isDefined) {
        sensors.put(sensorId, sensors.getOrElse(sensorId, HumidityData(0.0, 0)) match {
          case HumidityData(sum, count) => HumidityData(sum + humidity.get, count + 1)
        })
      } else {
        failedMeasurements += 1
      }
    })

    measurementSource.runWith(sink).onComplete(_ => {
      val numFilesProcessed = sensors.size
      val numMeasurementsProcessed = sensors.values.map(_.count).sum
      val numFailedMeasurements = failedMeasurements

      println(s"Num of processed files: $numFilesProcessed")
      println(s"Num of processed measurements: $numMeasurementsProcessed")
      println(s"Num of failed measurements: $numFailedMeasurements")

      val statsBySensor = sensors.map {
        case (sensorId, humidityData) =>
          val stats = SensorStats(
            min = Some(humidityData.sum / humidityData.count),
            avg = humidityData.avg,
            max = Some(humidityData.sum / humidityData.count)
          )
          (sensorId, stats)
      }

      println("Sensors with highest avg humidity:")
      println("sensor-id,min,avg,max")
      statsBySensor.toList.sortBy(_._2.avg).reverse.foreach {
        case (sensorId, stats) =>
          println(s"$sensorId,${stats.min.getOrElse("NaN")},${stats.avg.getOrElse("NaN")},${stats.max.getOrElse("NaN")}")
      }
      
      system.terminate()
    })
  }
}
```

build.sbt

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sensor-task"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.16",
)
```

.csv file data:-

| sensor-id | humidity |
| --- | --- |
| s1 | 80 |
| s3 | NaN |
| s2 | 78 |
| s1 | 98 |

Comment: Have you tried passing the absolute path?

Comment: Depending on the way you run your code, the "current directory" by not be the same (IDE Vs plain SBT for instance).

Comment: Yes I copied the absolute path of 'data' directory and it is not returning the results.

`D:\sensor-task> sbt "run sensor-task\src\main\scala\data"` and 
`D:\sensor-task> sbt "run D:\sensor-task\src\main\scala\data"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `sbt` commands (i.e. `sbt "run data"` and `sbt "run src/main/scala/data"`) look correct, with the assumption you're running `sbt` from the Scala project-root with source code under "src/main/scala/" and the csv files under "src/main/scala/data/".

A couple of observed issues with the code:

In creating `fileSource` there is a good possibility `new File().listFiles()` is getting more files than you intend to include (e.g. non csv files, hidden files, etc), resulting in a single blob after passing through `Framing.delimiter()` and subsequently dropped by `drop(1)`.  In such case, the "sensors" Map will be empty, resulting in all-0's in the output.

I was able to reproduce the all-0's result using your exact source code and "build.sbt" apparently due to non-csv files (in my test case, file ".DS_Store") included in `listFiles()`.

Providing specific file selection criteria for `listFiles()` such as including only "*.csv", like below, should fix the problem:

```
val fileSource = Source.fromIterator( () =>
  new File(directoryPath).listFiles((_, name) => name.endsWith(".csv")).iterator
)
```

Another issue is that the computation logic (`humidityData.sum / humidityData.count`) for the `min` and `max` are incorrect, essentially repeating the `avg` calculation.  To calculate them, one could expand the parameters in `HumidityData` as follows:

```
case class HumidityData(sum: Double, count: Int, min: Double, max: Double) {...}
```

The `min`/`max` could then be updated with something like below:

```
humidity match {
  case Some(h) =>
    sensors.put(sensorId, sensors.getOrElse(sensorId, HumidityData(0.0, 0, Double.MaxValue, 0.0)) match {
      case HumidityData(sum, count, min, max) =>
        HumidityData(sum + h, count + 1, Math.min(h, min), Math.max(h, max))
    })
  case None =>
    failedMeasurements += 1
}
```

As a side note, I would recommend separating data from code by moving data files away from under "src/main/scala/", and maybe place them under, say, "src/main/resources/data/".

Testing with the following csv data files ...

```
File src/main/resources/data/sensor_data1.csv:
sensor-id,humidity
s1,80
s3,NaN
s2,78
s1,98

File src/main/resources/data/sensor_data2.csv:
sensor-id,humidity
s1,70
s3,80
s2,60

$ sbt "run src/main/resources/data"
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.5 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_181)
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt ...
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/leo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /Users/leo/work/so-75459442/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to sensor-task (in build file:/Users/leo/work/so-75459442/)
[info] running HumiditySensorStatistics src/main/resources/data
Looking for CSV files in directory: src/main/resources/data
Num of processed sensors: 3
Num of processed measurements: 7
Num of failed measurements: 1
Sensors with highest avg humidity:
sensor-id,min,avg,max
s3,NaN,NaN,NaN
s1,70.0,82.66666666666667,98.0
s2,60.0,69.0,78.0
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 16, 2023 10:33:35 AM
```

Appended is the revised source code.

```
import java.io.File
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Framing, Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object HumiditySensorStatistics {

  case class HumidityData(sum: Double, count: Int, min: Double, max: Double) {
    def avg: Option[Double] = if (count > 0) Some(sum / count) else None
  }

  case class SensorStats(min: Option[Double], avg: Option[Double], max: Option[Double])

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val directoryPath = args(0)
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("HumiditySensorStatistics")
    // implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()  // Not needed for Akka Stream 2.6+
    val sensors = mutable.Map[String, HumidityData]()
    var failedMeasurements = 0

    println(s"Looking for CSV files in directory: $directoryPath")

    val fileSource = Source.fromIterator( () =>
      new File(directoryPath).listFiles((_, name) => name.endsWith(".csv")).iterator
    )
    val measurementSource = fileSource.flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(f.toPath))
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024, allowTruncation = true))
      .drop(1) // skip header line
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(line => {
        val fields = line.split(",")
        (fields(0), fields(1))
      })
    val sink = Sink.foreach[(String, String)](data => {
      val sensorId = data._1
      val humidity = data._2.toDoubleOption

      humidity match {
        case Some(h) =>
          sensors.put(sensorId, sensors.getOrElse(sensorId, HumidityData(0.0, 0, Double.MaxValue, 0.0)) match {
            case HumidityData(sum, count, min, max) =>
              HumidityData(sum + h, count + 1, Math.min(h, min), Math.max(h, max))
          })
        case None =>
          failedMeasurements += 1
      }
    })

    measurementSource.runWith(sink).onComplete(_ => {
      val numSensorsProcessed = sensors.size
      val numMeasurementsProcessed = sensors.values.map(_.count).sum
      val numFailedMeasurements = failedMeasurements

      println(s"Num of processed sensors: $numSensorsProcessed")
      println(s"Num of processed measurements: $numMeasurementsProcessed")
      println(s"Num of failed measurements: $numFailedMeasurements")

      val statsBySensor = sensors.map {
        case (sensorId, humidityData) =>
          val stats = SensorStats(
            min = Some(humidityData.min),
            avg = humidityData.avg,
            max = Some(humidityData.max)
          )
          (sensorId, stats)
      }

      println("Sensors with highest avg humidity:")
      println("sensor-id,min,avg,max")
      statsBySensor.toList.sortBy(_._2.avg).reverse.foreach {
        case (sensorId, stats) =>
          println(s"$sensorId,${stats.min.getOrElse("NaN")},${stats.avg.getOrElse("NaN")},${stats.max.getOrElse("NaN")}")
      }

      system.terminate()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: After I made all the changes, I get only ```Looking for CSV files in directory: src/main/resources/data``` on ```sbt "run src/main/resources/data"``` command. and when enter command like ```sbt "run data" it gives me 
Looking for CSV files in directory: data
Num of processed files: 0
Num of processed measurements: 0
Num of failed measurements: 0
Sensors with highest avg humidity:
sensor-id,min,avg,max
Sensors with no measurements:

Comment: I also restricted it  and ran the command as Admin.
Looking for CSV files in directory: src/main/resources/data
Processing file: leaderOne.csv
Processing file: sensor-data.csv
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 16 Feb, 2023 1:31:18 PM
Num of processed files: 3
Num of processed measurements: 7
Num of failed measurements: 1

i am not getting any of these 
```Sensors with highest avg humidity:
sensor-id,min,avg,max```

Comment: I did debug the code and found that ```sensors``` which is a  mutable Map remains empty all the time and has noting inside it. And i can't understand how it's working on your side.

Comment: The empty mutable Map was what I had encountered when `listFile()` included improper csv data. Did you try using the exact revised source code and test data I listed in my answer?  It would help if you have a minimal test dataset that can reproduce the all-0's result, in which case simply append it along with the `sbt` output to your question.

Comment: Yes i did use your code only. 
When adding `println(s"Added humidity reading $humidity for sensor $sensorId. Current data: ${sensors(sensorId)}, keys: ${sensors.keys}")` inside ```val sink``` data seems to be populated for sensors.  But when i tried to print sensor outside of ```val sink``` it's empty. Which also means when control reaches here ```val statsBySensor``` and sensors.map finds nothing inside the mutableMap. That could be the reason why it's not printing anything after `println("sensor-id,min,avg,max")` to the console.

Comment: If you're seeing `sensors` populated during the creation of `val source`, but not getting output from the `onComplete` callback, perhaps your app exits before the callback has a chance to complete.  Try append an `Await` at the end of the main app -- e.g. make `measurementSource.runWith(sink)` a `val` (e.g. `sensorStats`), followed by `sensorStats.onComplete(...)` and then `Await.ready(sensorStats, 2000.millis)`.

Comment: Started showing results. `s3,NaN,NaN,NaN s1,70.0,82.66666666666667,98.0 s2,60.0,69.0,78.0`. Accepted the answer.

Comment: Is this the correct way to show number of files processed:- 
`val files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles((_, name) => name.endsWith(".csv"))

val numFiles = files.length` Or should i simply use this without filter `    val files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles`

Comment: Since the files being processed in your stream are the filtered files, I would simply define `val files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles((_, name) => name.endsWith(".csv"))` before defining `val fileSource = Source.fromIterator(() => files.iterator)` and then use `files.length` in your stats output.